# Changing global variables using defuns

Tags: common-lisp

Is there any way to make a defun in common-lisp change global variables?  In the following example, is there any way to make foo have the value 3 from inside the function?

The example is from sbcl

---

- (defparameter foo "foo")

FOO

- foo

"foo"

- `(defun bar (y)
  (declare (special y))
  (print y)
  (setf y 3)
  (print y))`

BAR

- (bar foo)

"foo" 
3 
3

- foo

"foo"

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can use `setf` ([documented here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_setf_.htm)) to set the value of all variables, including global ones. For example:

```
(defparameter foo "foo") ; => FOO
(defun bar () (setf foo 3)) ; => BAR
foo ; => "foo"
(bar) ; => 3
foo ; => 3
```

The reason your function was not altering the value of `foo` was because your `setf` form was setting the value of `y` rather than `foo`.

EDIT:

Ah, I think I see what you want to do here. You can use the `set` function to do this; `(setq alpha "beta")` is (roughly) equivalent to `(set 'alpha "beta")`. So, if we change our function  to use `set`, we get:

```
(defparameter foo "foo")
(defun bar (sym) (set sym 3))
foo ; => "foo"
(bar 'foo)
foo ; => 3
```

Note that this isn't necessarily setting a global variable, though:

```
(defparameter baz 1)
(let ((baz 2))
  baz ; => 2
  (bar 'baz)
  baz) ; => 3
baz ; => 1
```

Comment: So is there any way to pass a global variable to a function and then have that function change that particular global argument?

Comment: Updated answer, do that help?

Comment: The questoin of how to pass by value and by reference is a frequent one.  This answer shows that (set sym value), when sym is passed into a function as a symbol, handles the pass by reference question, and allows the function to modify the passed variable. (Comment here to help Google find this response).